# Apache http client Read Timed Out

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using apache http client api 4.5 to access a server. When server is under heavy load I get the error

"[read] I/O error: Read timed out"

Here is my  configuration

```
private CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
private CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36";
private HttpClientContext httpContext = new HttpClientContext();
private RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setSocketTimeout(5000).
        setConnectTimeout(10000).build();

private PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

public MyHttpClient() {

    cm.setMaxTotal(50);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);

    HttpHost host = new HttpHost("localhost", 80);
    cm.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(host), 5);


    DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy retryStrategy = new DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(5, 1);


    SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
            .setSoKeepAlive(true)
            .setSoReuseAddress(true)
            .setTcpNoDelay(true)
            .setSoTimeout(10000).build();

    httpContext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
    HttpClientBuilder builder= HttpClients.custom();

    builder.setMaxConnPerRoute(50)
        .setConnectionManager(cm)
        .setConnectionTimeToLive(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
        .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
        .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
        .setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(retryStrategy)
        .setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy)
        .setRetryHandler(myRetryHandler);


    httpClient=builder.build();
}
```

I understand the cause of the issue

> The read timeout is the timeout on waiting to read data

But I want to know

1. if there is any way/configuration to avoid the read time out error
2. What may be optimum settings so that my client will not fail when server is under load.

I see a similar post here but not answered [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513826/apache-http-client-prints-read-i-o-error-read-timed-out)

Comment: Additional notes: Similar software exist in microsoft technology,which are performing well under load also. does .net/ms technology has extra features which makes them robust

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that error message is related to the response above it.   Notice the time offset.   If it was part of that response it would have the same time stamp as the lines of that response.    That is just the point where the time out happened and was logged.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for having such an error may be that the server closes HTTP connections upon having responded. If that is the case, then this error may be avoided by disabling connection reuse by the client, so there would be no need for the client to verify that the connection is still alive:

```
builder.setConnectionReuseStrategy( (response, context) -> false );
```